# Open bank account at Charles Schwab without social security number?

Tags: bank-account, social-security

The U.S. brokerage and bank [Charles Schwab](https://www.schwab.com/) requires a social security number to open an account.  You have a social security number but your spouse doesn't.  Both want to have bank accounts at Charles Schwab.  Is there a way to get a bank account for the spouse at Charles Schwab without a social security number?

The bank needs to be Charles Schwab specifically and other banks are not applicable. Also, the spouse is in the United States on an H-4 visa and cannot therefore get a social security number.

Comment: Did you try visiting a branch ? Calling the customer care might not be that helpful though. I once opened an account with BofA with my passport as I hadn't received my SSN number till then(but I went into the branch to do so ). And why don't you apply for a SSN ? It takes a week at max to get one.

Comment: The branch unfortunately says the same, that a social security number is required also for the spouse. I updated the question to say that the spouse cannot get a social security number. Sometimes a TIN (tax identification number) might be used in lieu of a social security number, but I'm not sure if that is the case here.

Comment: Did you ask them specifically if an [ITIN](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/general-itin-information) is acceptable to open an account at Schwab?

Comment: They also have a so-called "international" branch - dealing with clients from abroad who typically to not have an US social security number.